# Finding Values with overlapping dates

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a table in my SQL Server like this:

```
ID Tblcd TblNo  Location    TableType   StartDate   EndDate
---------------------------------------------------------------
2   B      4      2B4          M        2/5/2014    4/6/2016
2   B      4      2B4          M        4/7/2017    NULL
2   B      4      2B4          K        3/4/2016    NULL
3   A      3      3A3          L        2/7/2018    7/4/2018
3   A      3      3A3          L        2/5/2018    NULL
1   C      5      1C5          N        2/4/2011    NULL
1   B      4      1B4          M        8/9/2015    3/5/2017
```

I want to identify the row which has StartDate as 2/5/2018 which is actually overlapping with the previous entry

Tried using the below query, but unable to find the second entry. What am I missing here.

```
SELECT
    A.Id AS AId,
    B.Id AS BId,
    A.StartDate AS AStartDate,
    A.EndDate AS AEndDate,
    B.StartDate AS BStartDate,
    B.EndDate AS BEndDate
FROM    
    dbo.TableDates AS a
INNER JOIN  
    dbo.TableDates AS b ON (b.Id = a.Id AND b.TblCd = a.TblCd AND b.TblNo = a.TblNo)
WHERE   
    a.StartDate <= b.EndDate
    AND a.EndDate >= b.StartDate
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Comment: Hi, can you also post the expected result as a table?

Comment: I need the row 3 A 3 3A3 L 2/7/2018 7/4/2018 to be displayed . Thanks